# cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum"

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, installation

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfM2xz8Ko3k) youtube video in order to install Ethereum client on Ubuntu 15.10

First I installed Go language environment. Then I have build QT following [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Qt) wiki

After that I tried to download and install Ethereum CLI client with

```
go get -u github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum
```

But, I get the following error

```
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum (download)
package github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum (from $GOROOT)
    /home/cooldudeabhi/work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethereum (from $GOPATH)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

#### Error spotted

There is a typo in your command. Try:

```
go get -u github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/
```

Remove the last `ethereum`.

#### Install from repository

You can also use the official ethereum ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

After installing, run `geth account new` to create an account on your node.

#### Build from source

If everything else does not work try manually cloning and building:

- Deps:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -y git build-essential libgmp3-dev golang
  ```
- Build:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
  ```

  cd go-ethereum
  make geth

You can now run `./build/bin/geth` to start your node.

Answer (score 1):

The video you linked to is quite old, almost 2 years ago (2014).

According to
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu here are the steps for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev (skip this if you only want the last stable version)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

(For other platforms, see [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum).)

Comment: Can you post instructions for Linux? I was just following the video so I can get idea for my Linux machine

Comment: The question mentiones Ubuntu 15.10 though, so it is unlikely homebrew would help them.

Comment: oops, let me fix...  the video was 15mins long so was glancing and I missed the question

Answer (score 0):

****Go through these simple steps****

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ethereum